# Proxing HTTPS mobile app reqquests fail with 403 response when SSL proxy enabled

Tags: ssl, proxy, http-status-code-403, charles-proxy

When I run an IOS App through proxy using tools such as Charles, Burp suite and Proxyman I'm not able to see the full request (receiving 403 when SSL is enabled) of the final end point after loged in, and also the App just stop working(Just work when SSL is disabled). I would like to see what the full request looks like to do it using Postman and HttpClient in Java. Is there anything I could do in order to get status 200 like when SSl is disabled ?

Any help to try bypass it is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to [TLS fingerprinting](https://fingerprint.com/blog/what-is-tls-fingerprinting-transport-layer-security/).

Platforms like Cloudflare offer services to block bots and other non-browser traffic, which analyse low-level details of how a client makes connections, including the TLS fingerprint, and use this to spot unusual traffic. Because proxies like the ones you're using create separate upstream TLS connections when they intercept incoming connections, they can often end up sending HTTPS traffic where the TLS fingerprint the server sees doesn't match the HTTP headers, which is sufficient for the connection to be blocked as 'unusual'.

Defeating this is not easy. I also maintain an HTTPS debugging proxy called [HTTP Toolkit](https://httptoolkit.tech), where I've done some work to defeat this, by optimizing individual fields of TLS handshakes to avoid common blocks (some more details: https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/tls-fingerprinting-node-js/). You might have more success using HTTP Toolkit in this case, since it can successfully avoid 90% of these kinds of blocks at the moment.

(Note that HTTP Toolkit doesn't have automated setup for iOS yet, but you can still use it manually like any other debugging proxy - you just need to trust the certificate & set your proxy settings)

That said, this still won't work 100% of the time. This is a cat & mouse game between bots and site-scrapers and bot-blocking services, where the criteria are constantly changing & tightening, so there is no perfect solution. Your best bet is to keep trying different tools, and see which ones can make themselves look least suspicious while proxying your traffic.

Comment: Cloudflare detects httptoolkit intercepting iOS traffic.

Comment: @hldev for some server/client combos, you may need to force HTTP/2 for this, which HTTP Toolkit supports but doesn't use by default (just for simplicity really). You may be able to do this from the client (HTTP Toolkit will use HTTP/2 for any client who explicitly requires it via ALPN) or you can directly configure this as an option in the Pro settings. There's more details in the docs here: https://httptoolkit.com/docs/reference/settings-page/#http2-behaviour